# How to install db-core or any adapter in Windows 10 with Python (pip)

Tags: python, open-source, python-venv, dbt

For the last couple of days I've struggled to install Dbt in my Windows 10 box. It seems the best way is to emulate Linux, with WSL.

So, in order to help others to save their time and a few neurons, I decided to post a quick recipe in this thread. I summarized the whole process in 7 steps, together with a nice and complete tutorial

1. Enable WSL
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install
2. Install Linux Ubuntu
   https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-on-wsl2-on-windows-10#1-overview
3. Install Python
   As python3 comes with Ubuntu by default, you won't need to do anything in this step. Otherwise, you can always got to:
   https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/#requirements-for-installing-packages
4. Install Pip
   https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#creating-a-virtual-environment
5. Install VirtualEnv
   https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

I hope it helps. If not you can always post a message in this thread!

Best wishes,
I

Comment: Thank you for sharing valuable knowledge to the community!

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can run `dbt-core` on Windows is with Docker. I'm currently on Windows 10 and use a Docker image for my dbt project without needing WSL. Below is my Dockerfile and requirements.txt file with `dbt-core` and `dbt-snowflake` but feel free to swap the packages you need.

In my repo, my dbt project is in a folder at the root level named dbt.

**requirements.txt**

```
dbt-core==1.1.0
dbt-snowflake==1.1.0
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/docker/library/python:3.8-slim-buster

COPY . /dbt

# Update and install system packages
RUN apt-get update -y && \
  apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y -q \
  git libpq-dev python-dev && \
  apt-get clean && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Install dbt
RUN pip install -U pip
RUN pip install -r dbt/requirements.txt
# TEMP FIX due to dependency updates. See https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/4745
RUN pip install --force-reinstall MarkupSafe==2.0.1

# Install dbt dependencies
WORKDIR /dbt
RUN dbt deps

# Specify profiles directory
ENV DBT_PROFILES_DIR=.dbt

# Expose port for dbt docs
EXPOSE 8080
```

And then you can build and run it (I personally put both of these commands in a dbt_run.sh file and run with `bash dbt_run.sh`):

```
docker build -t dbt_image .
docker run \
-p 8080:8080 \
--env-file .env \
-it \
--mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)",target=/dbt \
dbt_image bash
```

If you make changes to your dbt project while the container is running they will be reflected in the container which makes it great for developing locally. Hope this helps!